# MATLAB: ordering pixel locations or path in 3d skeletonized line

Tags: matlab, 3d, line

I have a series of vascular objects in a 3d matrix. I've isolated each and used Skeleton3D to skeletonize them (so now I have a bunch of matrices with a twisty line segment (no branching)). I would like to now move along the length of each skeleton from tip to tip and perform an operation at each point...just don't know how to find the ends of the line or the path.

So in the code below I would need the pixelorder vector containing 3d pixel locations starting at one end of a twisty 3d line and working its way to the other end.

```
    for i=1:length(pixelorder)
        someoperation(pixelorder(i));
    end
```

I started on some code doing the middle-out approach. It runs through the z-axis and looks for a slice where there is only one pixel value equal to one (i know this is wishful thinking..but if its there it should be a cross-section of the line). From there I take a 3x3x3 neighborhood around the pixel (pixel at 2,2,2), and look for other values equal to one. I then check the distances from the center pixel to any in that neighborhood that equal one. I took the two minimum distances pixels that are the minimum distance from the center pixel and say that's either direction of the line. In case of a turn (i.e. 1 value pixels at the 2,2,2 center, 2,2,1..2,2,3 and then a turn at 1,2,3) i remove pixels adjacent (distance==1) to the nearest pixel to the center.

The plan is then to move in both directions with a similar strategy building vectors in either direction that I combine at the end.

I'm setting the center value in each neighborhood to zero as I process it...should hit the end of the line when I run out of pixel==1 values?

Hoping this makes sense..

The segments start and end in random locations irrespective of axis and twist around so I can't just iterate through one axis.

```
 skel=skel2;%padarray(skel2,[1,1,1],0,'both');
skelcopy=skel;
vectorforward=[];
vectorbackward=[];
for i=1:z
    if sum(sum(skel(:,:,i)))==0
        continue
    elseif sum(sum(skel(:,:,i)))==1 %doesnt really work if there's no single point in this/any dimension
        [startrow,startcol]=find(skel(:,:,i)==1);
        startind=sub2ind(size(skel),startrow,startcol,i);
        vectorforward(end+1)=startind;
        skelcopy(startrow,startcol,i)=0;
        checksize=1;
        truelocind=find(skelcopy(startrow-checksize:startrow+checksize,startcol-checksize:startcol+checksize,i-checksize:i+checksize)==1);
        xrow=startrow-checksize:startrow+checksize;
        ycol=startcol-checksize:startcol+checksize;
        islice=i-checksize:i+checksize;
        truelocsubs=[];
        dists=[];
        matsize=size(skelcopy(startrow-checksize:startrow+checksize,startcol-checksize:startcol+checksize,i-checksize:i+checksize));

        indmat=zeros(matsize);
        for im=1:matsize(1)
            for jm=1:matsize(2)
                for km=1:matsize(3)
                    indmat(im,jm,km)=sub2ind(size(skel),xrow(im),ycol(jm),islice(km));%sub2ind(size(skel),j,i,k);
                end
            end
        end      
        for j=1:length(truelocind)
            [truelocsubs(j,1),truelocsubs(j,2),truelocsubs(j,3)]=ind2sub(matsize,truelocind(j));
            dists(j)=norm((matsize/2+0.5)-truelocsubs(j,:));
        end
        [sortlist,sortorder]=sort(dists);
        if length(sortlist)>2
            if sortlist(3)>sortlist(2)
                closeinds=indmat(truelocind(sortorder(1:2)));
            else %in case of turn: 3x3x3 neighborhood has values at 2,2,1..2,2,2..2,2,3..1,2,3
                closeinds=indmat(truelocind(sortorder(1))); %selects closest pixel
                dists2=[];
                for j=1:length(truelocind)
                    dists2(j)=norm(truelocsubs(sortorder(1),:)-truelocsubs(j,:)); %distances of other connected pixels from closest
                end
                adjacents=find(dists2==1);
                adjacents(end+1)=find(dists2==0);
                truelocind(adjacents)=[]; %removes pixels that are part of turn from selection
                sortorder(adjacents)=[];
                closeinds(end+1)=indmat(truelocind(sortorder(1)));
            end
        elseif length(sortlist)==2
            closeinds=indmat(truelocind(sortorder(1:2)));
        else
            disp('line end')
        end
            vectorforward(end+1)=closeinds(1);
            vectorbackward(end+1)=closeinds(2);
        % forwards
        while length(truelocind)>0
            center=vectorforward(end);%closeinds(1);%...do the stuff with that...find new closeind(1      
            [startrow,startcol,zloc]=ind2sub(size(skel),center);         
            startind=center;%sub2ind(size(skel),startrow,startcol,zloc);
            skelcopy(startrow,startcol,zloc)=0;
            checksize=1;
            truelocind=find(skelcopy(startrow-checksize:startrow+checksize,startcol-checksize:startcol+checksize,zloc-checksize:zloc+checksize)==1);
            xrow=startrow-checksize:startrow+checksize;
            ycol=startcol-checksize:startcol+checksize;
            islice=zloc-checksize:zloc+checksize;
            truelocsubs=[];
            dists=[];
            matsize=size(skelcopy(startrow-checksize:startrow+checksize,startcol-checksize:startcol+checksize,zloc-checksize:zloc+checksize));

            indmat=zeros(matsize);
            for im=1:matsize(1)
                for jm=1:matsize(2)
                    for km=1:matsize(3)
                        indmat(im,jm,km)=sub2ind(size(skel),xrow(im),ycol(jm),islice(km));%sub2ind(size(skel),j,zloc,k);
                    end
                end
            end      
            for j=1:length(truelocind)
                [truelocsubs(j,1),truelocsubs(j,2),truelocsubs(j,3)]=ind2sub(matsize,truelocind(j));
                dists(j)=norm((matsize/2+0.5)-truelocsubs(j,:));
            end
            [sortlist,sortorder]=sort(dists);
            if length(sortlist)>1
                disp('check')
                if sortlist(2)>sortlist(1)
                    closeinds=indmat(truelocind(sortorder(1)));
                else %in case of turn: 3x3x3 neighborhood has values at 2,2,1..2,2,2..2,2,3..1,2,3
                    disp('sup?')
                    closeinds=indmat(truelocind(sortorder(1))); %selects closest pixel
                    dists2=[];
                    for j=1:length(truelocind)
                        dists2(j)=norm(truelocsubs(sortorder(1),:)-truelocsubs(j,:)); %distances of other connected pixels from closest
                    end
                    adjacents=find(dists2==1);
                    adjacents(end+1)=find(dists2==0);
                    truelocind(adjacents)=[]; %removes pixels that are part of turn from selection
                    sortorder(adjacents)=[];
                    closeinds(end+1)=indmat(truelocind(sortorder(1)));
                end
            elseif length(sortlist)==1
                closeinds=indmat(truelocind(sortorder(1)));
            else
                disp('end line')
            end
                vectorforward(end+1)=closeinds(1);
            end
        % backwards
  truelocind='startbackwards';      
        while length(truelocind)>0
            center=vectorbackward(end);%closeinds(1);%...do the stuff with that...find new closeind(1      
            [startrow,startcol,zloc]=ind2sub(size(skel),center);         
            startind=center;%sub2ind(size(skel),startrow,startcol,zloc);
            skelcopy(startrow,startcol,zloc)=0;
            checksize=1;
            truelocind=find(skelcopy(startrow-checksize:startrow+checksize,startcol-checksize:startcol+checksize,zloc-checksize:zloc+checksize)==1);
            xrow=startrow-checksize:startrow+checksize;
            ycol=startcol-checksize:startcol+checksize;
            islice=zloc-checksize:zloc+checksize;
            truelocsubs=[];
            dists=[];
            matsize=size(skelcopy(startrow-checksize:startrow+checksize,startcol-checksize:startcol+checksize,zloc-checksize:zloc+checksize));

            indmat=zeros(matsize);
            for im=1:matsize(1)
                for jm=1:matsize(2)
                    for km=1:matsize(3)
                        indmat(im,jm,km)=sub2ind(size(skel),xrow(im),ycol(jm),islice(km));%sub2ind(size(skel),j,zloc,k);
                    end
                end
            end      
            for j=1:length(truelocind)
                [truelocsubs(j,1),truelocsubs(j,2),truelocsubs(j,3)]=ind2sub(matsize,truelocind(j));
                dists(j)=norm((matsize/2+0.5)-truelocsubs(j,:));
            end
            [sortlist,sortorder]=sort(dists);
            if length(sortlist)>1
                if sortlist(2)>sortlist(1)
                    closeinds=indmat(truelocind(sortorder(1)));
                else %in case of turn: 3x3x3 neighborhood has values at 2,2,1..2,2,2..2,2,3..1,2,3
                    disp('sup?')
                    closeinds=indmat(truelocind(sortorder(1))); %selects closest pixel
                    dists2=[];
                    for j=1:length(truelocind)
                        dists2(j)=norm(truelocsubs(sortorder(1),:)-truelocsubs(j,:)); %distances of other connected pixels from closest
                    end
                    adjacents=find(dists2==1);
                    adjacents(end+1)=find(dists2==0);
                    truelocind(adjacents)=[]; %removes pixels that are part of turn from selection
                    sortorder(adjacents)=[];
                    closeinds(end+1)=indmat(truelocind(sortorder(1)));
                end
            elseif length(sortlist)==1
                closeinds=indmat(truelocind(sortorder(1)));
            else
                disp('end line')
            end
                vectorbackward(end+1)=closeinds(1);

 end

        break
    end 
end
vectorbackward(end)=[];
vectorforward(end)=[];
pixelorder=[vectorbackward,vectorforward];
```

Comment: Starting from any white pixel, iterate over its neighbors and append it to a list. At some point, while jumping from pixel to pixel one will have no more neighbours. That is the first(or last) pixel

Comment: Another way to find the start and end points is by counting the number of neighbors of each pixel -- start and end points have only one neighbor, other points have two.

Comment: @CrisLuengo since its 3d, couldn't an end of a point have 2 neighbors? (like in a 3x3 neighborhood with the end at 2,2,2...there could be values at 2,2,3 and 2,3,3 if the line takes a turn?)..maybe I'm just not understanding skeletons

Comment: A skeleton is thin w.r.t. a certain connectivity. If you generated a 26-connected skeleton (i.e. each pixel has 26 neighbors, including face, edge and vertex neighbors), then the configuration that you describe cannot exist because it's not a thin skeleton, one of those pixels would have been removed. If, on the other hand, you generated a 6-connected skeleton (i.e. only face neighbors are considered neighbors), then the configuration you describe could exist, but the three pixels would not be neighbors of each other. By definition, the skeleton pixels have 1 neighbor it they're end points.

Comment: Got it thanks! (thought that might be the case)